# Javaagent. What for?

Tags: java, bytecode, javaagents

When I try to find examples of using Javaagent, in most cases they are examples with working with byte-code. These examples use third-party libraries, such as Javaassist.

As far as I know there are no standard means in Java to work with byte-code and in any case you'll have to resort to the libraries.

So, I tried to use these libraries in my own custom classloader before calling `defineClass()`. And, off course, it worked perfectly well. I could change byte-code the same way, as if I would do it with `ClassFileTransformer`'s `transform()` method.

Do I understand correctly that there is another useful feature of javaagents, that in turn is their main feature? Because, first of all, javaagent gives you an `Instrumentation` object and the Java spec says that the `instrument` package is mainly used to work with byte-code. But why do I need to do that if I just can implement my own classloader (the thing I could do long before the `instrument` package was introduced)?

Answer (score 4):

The Instrumentation API can be used at runtime without touching the code nor the compiled byte code. You can instrument every compiled java program (even without having the code).

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I'm humbly sorry, but all they did in the article is used byte code transformation with ASM. The same could be done with a classloader

Comment: OK, different example: Write a profiler that can counts the number of classes loaded/used by a java application. Then use it to profile, lets say Apache Tomcat Webserver. How could you do that using a custom classloader?

Comment: I'm forced to agree with you )) no way I can do it using only my custom class loader

Answer (score 3):

I think using javaagent is different because it is not part of your application. You can write eg a profiling agent and use it with any application.

Comment: It's pretty sensible. 
But as far as I understand Mockito for instance uses a javaagent to operate byte-code. Mockito attaches the javaagent to JVM. But if it's the only purpose of their javaagent, they could simply use their own classloader.
Perhaps I don't understand something =)

Comment: I think Mockito builds proxies on the fly at runtime, just like Spring AOP, though its only my guess

Answer (score 1):

Don’t mix up Javaagents and Instrumentation. A Java agent can use instrumentation but it doesn’t have to. It can use all other features the Java platform offers. The typical example of an agent not using instrumentation is the JMX agent. Look at what tools like `JVisualVM` offer. Most of it’s features (with the exception of the profiler) are provided through the JMX agent without using instrumentation.

By the way, regarding your question about the difference between instrumentation and class loaders. A custom class loader cannot change classes loaded through the bootstrap class loader like `java.lang.Object` (though you should think twice before doing this). Further, your custom class loader had to implement the original class loaders semantic to work. Otherwise, e.g. if you try to intercept loading using delegation, your class loader would miss all classes loaded when the JVM tries to resolve dependencies. And all classes loaded by another `ClassLoader` created by the application (e.g. by RMI) would not get handled by your custom class loader.

So, Instrumentation adds a way to process classes independent of their `ClassLoader` and (optionally) even allow to change them on demand *after* loading.